# why is this function firing on all child menu items as well?

Tags: functions, menus, sub-menu, dropdown

I'm using this simple function to add a dropdown indicator to my menu. However, I am getting a dropdown indicator on all children of the `<li>` that has the class `menu-item-has-children`. How do I change this so it only shows the indicator on the parent menu item?

```
add_filter( 'nav_menu_link_attributes', 'wpse154485_add_aria_haspopup_atts', 10, 3 );
function wpse154485_add_aria_haspopup_atts( $atts, $item, $args ) {
  if (in_array('menu-item-has-children', $item->classes)) {
    $args->link_after = "</span><span class='caret'><i class='dropdown-indicator'></i></span>";
  }
  return $atts;
}
```

**Edit**: As requested, here is a vardump of one of the menu items that I do *not* want to show the dropdown indicator (but which currently is showing it).

```
object(WP_Post)#1695 (47) {
  ["ID"]=>
  int(9775)
  ["post_author"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["post_date"]=>
  string(19) "2017-01-11 00:23:04"
  ["post_date_gmt"]=>
  string(19) "2017-01-11 05:23:04"
  ["post_content"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["post_title"]=>
  string(18) "Blog"
  ["post_excerpt"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["post_status"]=>
  string(7) "publish"
  ["comment_status"]=>
  string(6) "closed"
  ["ping_status"]=>
  string(6) "closed"
  ["post_password"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["post_name"]=>
  string(16) "blog"
  ["to_ping"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["pinged"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["post_modified"]=>
  string(19) "2017-01-25 10:38:11"
  ["post_modified_gmt"]=>
  string(19) "2017-01-25 15:38:11"
  ["post_content_filtered"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["post_parent"]=>
  int(0)
  ["guid"]=>
  string(29) "http://localhost:8888/?p=9775"
  ["menu_order"]=>
  int(5)
  ["post_type"]=>
  string(13) "nav_menu_item"
  ["post_mime_type"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["comment_count"]=>
  string(1) "0"
  ["filter"]=>
  string(3) "raw"
  ["db_id"]=>
  int(9775)
  ["menu_item_parent"]=>
  string(4) "9779"
  ["object_id"]=>
  string(4) "9772"
  ["object"]=>
  string(4) "page"
  ["type"]=>
  string(9) "post_type"
  ["type_label"]=>
  string(4) "Page"
  ["url"]=>
  string(34) "http://localhost:8888/blog/"
  ["title"]=>
  string(18) "Blog"
  ["target"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["attr_title"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["description"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["classes"]=>
  array(4) {
    [0]=>
    string(0) ""
    [1]=>
    string(9) "menu-item"
    [2]=>
    string(24) "menu-item-type-post_type"
    [3]=>
    string(21) "menu-item-object-page"
  }
  ["xfn"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["extended_activate"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["highlight_menu"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["extended_columns"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["extended_heading"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["extended_disable_link"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["extended_text_chk"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["extended_free_text"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["current"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["current_item_ancestor"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["current_item_parent"]=>
  bool(false)
}
```

In this case, the Blog menu item is a child & doesn't have the 'menu-item-has-children' class. However, its parent item does have it.

Comment: can you add the output of `var_dump($item);` to your question, so we know what properties the item has please

Comment: @DavidLee see above (edited post)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$args` parameter are the arguments of the entire menu not of the single menu item, you can see it [here](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.7/src/wp-includes/class-walker-nav-menu.php#L176) in the file itself that uses and executes the filter:

> @param stdClass $args  An object of wp_nav_menu() arguments.

so when your `IF` is true (the item is a parent item), you are modifying the entire Menu arguments:

```
$args->link_after = "</span><span class='caret'><i class='dropdown-indicator'></i></span>";
```

so all menu items after the parent item would have the dropdown indicator.

If you want to add the dropdown indicator you will have to do the classic `custom walker` way, where you create your own class:

```
class Custom_Nav_Walker extends Walker_Nav_Menu{}
```

and override the `start_el` function, you will find plenty of info about it.

Comment: I already have a custom walker w/ custom classes. The issue is possibly a CSS one then? I thought I needed some extra markup to be added to the parent-items to do this dropdown-indicator. So I could potentially just add some CSS to .menu-item-has-children to pull this off?

Comment: yeah, If you already have a custom walker you can add logic there to add the dropdown indicator when the menu item is being concatenated (personal preference) and yes you can use `CSS` only too , my answer is to explain why the function was adding the dropdown icon to all the children.